# Preview-LaTeX does not work when using natbib (on Emacs 24.5.1, AUCTeX 11.89)

Tags: natbib, preview

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} 
\begin{document}
$\alpha$
\bibliographystyle{ims}
\bibliography{mybibliography}
\end{document}
```

Preview-latex does not work with above code. It works if I remove

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

I think there is some problem between preview-latex, natbib, and -file-line-error.

Here is error message:

> ```
> Running `Preview-LaTeX' on `_region_' with ``xelatex  -file-line-error  --synctex=1 "\nonstopmode\nofiles\PassOptionsToPackage{active,tightpage,auctex}{preview}\AtBeginDocument{\ifx\ifPreview\undefined\RequirePackage[displaymath,floats,graphics,textmath,sections,footnotes]{preview}[2004/11/05]\fi}" "\input" "_region_.tex"''
> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9)
> entering extended mode
> LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
> Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
>
> No auxiliary output files.
>
> (_region_.tex  !name(test.tex)
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
> Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty"
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty:795: LaTeX Error:
>  \makeindex undefined.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help
> )
> No file _region_.aux.
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\preview\preview.sty"
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\preview\prtightpage.def")
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\preview\prauctex.def"
> No auxiliary output files.
>
>
> ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\preview\prfootnotes.def")
> Preview: Fontsize 12pt
> Preview: PDFoutput 1
> )  !name(test.tex) !offset(-3)
> _region_.tex:7: Preview: Snippet 1 started
> Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
> _region_.tex:7: Preview: Snippet 1 ended.(338603+0x494792)
> [1]
>
> Package natbib Warning: Citation `PKH15' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
>
> No file _region_.bbl.
>
> Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
>
>  )
> (see the transcript file for additional information)
> Output written on _region_.pdf (1 page).
> SyncTeX written on _region_.synctex.gz.
> Transcript written on _region_.log.
>
> TeX Output exited as expected with code 1 at Thu Aug 25 14:05:28
> LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images
> ```

Thank you in advance